# Seeking Seabed Survey Data Model (SSDM)?

Tags: spatial-database, data-model

Many of the offshore oil/gas companies are adopting an initiative from Shell for delivery of spatial data.  This is called an SSDM, which is really an ESRI file geodatabase with a standardised structure of datasets, and featureclasses.

An empty template (geodatabase) in the SSDM structure is freely available from the OGP website, but it would be really good if anyone knows of an example geodatabase which is fully verified so we can use it as a 'how to' reference guide.

Does anyone know if such a thing exists?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really a "best practice" for SSDM but using the data dictionary in conjunction with populating the data model is a huge help.  The "best practice" is to reference the associated data dictionary (the OGP model has one) with what attribute should be used in each field.  Additionally, look at the geometry of each feature class to determine if you need to load data Z- and/or M- enabled.

Typically we port our cad or shapefile exports from various post processing softwares to load to SSDM.  Then populate the associated attributes, etc.  The simple data loader (right click FC -> data -> load data) should be used to load data.